# Can't Open file after saving with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I run my python script for data validation task I make changes using openpyxl data validation & save it.

Now when i tried to open excel file it displays loading & loading But can not open.

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import copy
import re
excel_file_path = r"C:\Users\Downloads\Net_v2.7.xlsx"
wb  = load_workbook(excel_file_path,read_only=False)
def replace_dropdown(sheet, cell,dropdowntype):
    toRemove = []
    bit = []
    cell_pos = []
    if ':' in cell:
        cell_r = cell.split(":")
        col_names = list(map(chr,range(ord(cell_r[0][0]),ord(cell_r[1][0])+1)))
        for col in col_names:
            start_index,end_index = map(int,re.findall(r'\d+',cell))
            for i in range(int(start_index),int(end_index)+1):
                        cell1 = f'{col}{i}'
                        cell_pos.append(cell1)
    else:
        cell_pos.append(cell)
    for validation in sheet.data_validations.dataValidation:
        if validation.formula1  == dropdowntype:
                toRemove.append(validation)
                import ipdb
                ipdb.set_trace()
                break
    for ii in toRemove:
        sheet.data_validations.dataValidation.remove(ii)
    #here we get validation cells
    if len(toRemove)>0:
        dvd = toRemove
        dv =dvd[0]
        # dv = DataValidation(type = "list",formula1=dropdowntype,showDropDown=False)
        cell_range1 = f"{toRemove[0].sqref}"
        bit = cell_range1.split()
        cell_range = []
    # here we get validation cells
    if len(bit)>1:
        for i in bit:
            sheet_val = True
            if ':' in i:
                start_index,end_index = map(int,re.findall(r'\d+',i))
                start_col,end_col = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]+)',i)
                # for start_col in col_names:
                for i in range(int(start_index),int(end_index)+1):
                        cell1 = f'{start_col}{i}'
                        cell_range.append(cell1)
                        cell2 = f'{end_col}{i}'
                        cell_range.append(cell2)
            else:
                 cell_range.append(i)
    else:
        if len(bit) == 1:
            start_index,end_index = map(int,re.findall(r'\d+',bit[0]))
            for start_col in col_names:
                for i in range(int(start_index),int(end_index)+1):
                    cell1 = f'{start_col}{i}'
                    cell_range.append(cell1)
    # here we set validation on cells
    if len(toRemove)>0:
        dv.sqref = []
        import ipdb
        ipdb.set_trace()
        if sheet_val == False:
            for cell_cor in cell_range:
                if cell_cor not in cell_pos and cell_cor in dv:
                    sheet.add_data_validation(dv)
                    dv.add(sheet[cell_cor])
                else:
                    pass
        elif sheet_val == True:
            for cell_cor in cell_range:
                if cell_cor not in  cell_pos :
                    sheet.add_data_validation(dv)
                    dv.add(sheet[cell_cor])       
li1 = [
    {
    "T": "Network Issue",
    "v": 2.454547,
    "Tab Name": "thanked",
    "Change Type": "Change Dropdown",
    "cell_NameRG": "K447:K552",
    "column_name": "K",
    "Released in": None,
    "Old_v": "You jsut",
    "New_v": None
}]
for i in li1:
    sheet =i['Tab Name']
    cell = i["cell_NameRG"]
    old_v = i["Old_v"]
    new_v = i["New_v"]
    col_N = i["column_name"]
    replace_dropdown(wb[sheet],cell,old_v,new_v,col_N)

wb.save("task_1.xlsx")
```

I am executing this function then when i tried to open excel wb it can't open

After executing this function ,excel file can not open!

Can Anyone tell me what's wrong with this function.

Comment: Where do you save the result? In code.

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not known what your function does or what format the input it expects should be.